# Android paho simple explanation for subscribing to a topic

Tags: android, mqtt

I am trying to create a simple android app that controls my robot. All the communication is done using mqtt and eclipse paho for android, but I am very new to the protocol. I cannot find a simple explanation of how to get data from a subscribed topic. The best one I found was [HiveMQ android tutorial](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-enyclopedia-paho-android-service)
but that did not explain how to get the data from the callbacks. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

For android I have used Paho Android project, very simple to use, here are the steps:

Intialize a client, set required options and connect.

```
MqttAndroidClient mqttClient = new MqttAndroidClient(BaseApplication.getAppContext(), broker, MQTT_CLIENT_ID);
//Set call back class
mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackHandler(BaseApplication.getAppContext()));
MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
IMqttToken token = mqttClient.connect(connOpts);
```

Subscribe to a topic.

```
token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(IMqttToken arg0) {
       mqttClient.subscribe("TOPIC_NAME" + userId, 2, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Successfully subscribed to topic.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Failed to subscribed to topic.");
            }
        });
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(IMqttToken arg0, Throwable arg1) {
       Log.d(LOG_TAG, errorMsg);
  }
});
```

Define your callback handler class.

```
public class MqttCallbackHandler implements MqttCallbackExtended {
    @Override
        public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
            Log.w("mqtt", s);
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
            Log.w("Anjing", mqttMessage.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

        }
  }
```

Also set following in manifest file.

```
<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
</service>
```

Would recommend visiting their project on GitHub and going through samples online.

[Eclipse Paho Android](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android)

Hoping this helps. If you have more questions please visit
[Android step by step guide using Eclipse Paho](http://blogsbysachin.blogspot.com/2016/08/mqtt-android-step-by-step-guide-using.html)

Cheers !